# Start processing before SSL/TLS negotiation completes?

Tags: php, apache, ssl, networking

So looking at network time information for HTTPS page being loaded, one can see that (in my case) SSL/TLS negotiation takes ~50ms (a significant part of whole page). My understanding is that that server should now url before negotiation completes, and one could assume that negotiation mostly always succeeds. So it would seem that web server could start processing request before negotiation completes?

Does anyone know if that can be done (like web server option, start processing before negotiation completes)? Maybe it is already being done? Some reasons why it is not possible? Or why this is stupid idea?

Comment: you measure your page in ms , tell me more

Comment: what's the problem with 50ms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server does *not* know the URL before TLS negotiation completes. The requested URL is the first of the HTTP headers, which are wrapped and encrypted *inside* the TLS tunnel. Before the TLS tunnel is established the client cannot send and the server can't receive the HTTP headers.

Comment: Ah yes, correct. Though I know that I somehow though that first client send request data encrypted servers public key and then some finalizing processing is being done. But for security that can't be, as client might be sending data to imposer, all must be finalized before anything is sent.